# GitHub action self-host runner as service fails

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemd, github-actions-self-hosted-runners, github-actions-runners

I have installed GitHub `self-hosted runner` on my Ubuntu system. Getting below error when i try to configure it as service.

```
$ sudo ./svc.sh start
Failed to start actions.runner._services.Linux-Host01.service: Unit actions.runner._services.Linux-Host01.service is not loaded properly: Exec format error.
See system logs and 'systemctl status actions.runner._services.Linux-Host01.service' for details.
Failed: failed to start actions.runner._services.Linux-Host01.service
```

```
$ systemctl status actions.runner._services.Linux-Host01.service
● actions.runner._services.Linux-Host01.service - GitHub Actions Runner (_services.Linux-Host01)
   Loaded: error (Reason: Exec format error)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/actions.runner._services.Linux-Host01.service
[Unit]
Description=GitHub Actions Runner (_services.Linux-Host01)
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/admin.user/actions-runner/runsvc.sh
User=admin.user
WorkingDirectory=/home/admin.user/actions-runner
KillMode=process
KillSignal=SIGTERM
TimeoutStopSec=5min

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

```
$ sudo journalctl -u actions.runner._services.Linux-Host01.service -f

Aug 04 08:40:47 Linux-Host01 systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/actions.runner._services.Linux-Host01.service:7: Invalid user/group name or numeric ID: admin.user
```

Additionally have provided executable permission to `actions.runner._services.Linux-Host01.service` but still it results same error.

What is wrong here?

Comment: `I have provided executable permission` No, remove them, that's a service file. `Exec format error` You have to run sh or bash or the shell you are using. `ExecStart=/bin/sh /home/admin.user/actions-runner/runsvc.sh`

Comment: i did that, still same problem occurring.

Comment: From the tag: systemd questions should be for *programming questions* using systemd or its libraries. Questions about *configuring the daemon* (including writing unit files) are better directed to Unix & Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed `User=admin.user` to `User=uid` in the `/etc/systemd/system/actions.runner._services.Linux-Host01.service` file and then executed

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

Now action service started and it is running fine.

Comment: Check my answer as the appropriate way to address this.

Answer (score 4):

This simply means you've not installed the runner

1. `sudo ./svc.sh install` // install the runner
2. `sudo ./svc.sh start` // then start it

Remember, this is the best way to go about it than using the `./run.sh` script, as the runner will always be running in the background.

Use `sudo ./svc.sh status` to confirm that the runner is up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Good morning,

First of all stop the service:

```
sudo ./svc.sh stop
```

Then make sure you have given permissions to the user:

```
sudo usermod -a -G <USER>
```

Now try to start the service:

```
sudo ./svc.sh start
```

And tell me if this works when check the status.

If not works please do the same but sudo permissions:

```
sudo su
```

And then try again all without sudo command because you are actually on root.

Have a great day!

Comment: Good Morning, Firstly thank you so much for assisting me. The above steps unfortunately didn't help. Even i have tried by removing and installing the runner again, however still same issue.

Comment: Good morning, can you try to uninstall again with `sudo ./svc.sh uninstall`. Now please follow the steps using alternative installation `./svc.sh install USERNAME`. You can follow documentation here: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/configuring-the-self-hosted-runner-application-as-a-service

Comment: Good Afternoon, Have tried the same yesterday itself. but even this `sudo ./svc.sh uninstall` also fails, It was saying failed to stop and uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be the value of the environment variable $SUDO_USER. Inside svc.sh, it captures it:

```
run_as_user=${arg_2:-$SUDO_USER}
```

And then uses sed to inject the user value into the systemd service file:

```
sed "s/{{User}}/${run_as_user}/g;
```

This becomes an issue if you performed all the installation of the runner as root and then $SUDO_USER evaluates to a nonroot user. For example, if you are automating the script in the user_data script of an EC2 Instance, make sure to change the ownership of the actions-runner directory to the user that evaluates to $SUDO_USER. In my case, since I use the SSM Agent to connect to ec2 instances, it will be ssm-user (if you use amazon linux 2023, it would be ec2-user and if you use ubuntu, then it would be ubuntu as user).

```
chown ssm-user -R /actions-runner
./svc.sh install
./svc.sh start
```